# Как убрать "403 Forbidden" при загрузке файлов WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, ssl

Нужно перенести сайт

```
https://go2chernobyl.com/
```

который имеет действительный SSL-сертификат, на сайт

```
http://2000.dream-line.com.ua/
```

Сайт работает на WordPress. Были изменены все ссылки в базе данных, выключена https-переадресация в ".htaccess". С правами на файлы все в порядке - "644", папки - "755".

Проблема в том что попытка WordPress загрузить любой файл получает "403 Forbidden".

Возмем к примеру

```
http://2000.dream-line.com.ua/wp-content/themes/go2chernobyl/style.css
```

Весьма странно, что к этому файлу можно получить доступ через

```
https://2000.dream-line.com.ua/wp-content/themes/go2chernobyl/style.css
```

Сервис проверки SSL-сертификатов каким-то образом нашел сертификат оригинального сайта на новом:

```
https://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-checker.html#hostname=2000.dream-line.com.ua
```

Для сравнения:

```
https://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-checker.html#hostname=go2chernobyl.com
```

Как убрать "403 Forbidden" при загрузке файлов?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема решилась нашим админом :)

По его словам на корневой папке права были '751', нужно было '755'.

Что касается SSL-сертификата, то скорее всего он был обнаружен по IP.